# Tag organisation - reputation reward inconsistency?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm quite new on Ask Ubuntu but have been getting stuck in, mostly answering, some editing, some retagging.

I noticed that while I was at low reputation and needed approval to tweak tags, I would get +2 once it was approved.

I recently passed the threshold to be able to edit tags all on my own, and now I don't seem to get the +2 for it anymore.

This seems inconsistent to me, should it be this way? I realise it could probably be abused to point-whore, but as it is now there's no incentive (yes, helping the community is the incentive) to fix up tags, while they're quite an important organisational tool of the site.

Comment: Now to get [Strunk & White](http://askubuntu.com/badges/12/strunk-white), then [Copy Editor](http://askubuntu.com/badges/49/copy-editor). :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an authority on the SE software but it seems to be that it's there to encourage you to try something else to improve the site. Basically, it looks like you've graduated tag wiki school and are ready for something new.

We're always in need of more editors, you get your +2 and there's some good badges there, as well as a new review UI that makes it awesome:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/review-early-review-often/

And here are some tips on editing:

- [Editing tips and tricks](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)
- [Our answered rate keeps plummeting, ideas to improve this?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1340/our-answered-rate-keeps-plummeting-ideas-to-improve-this)

So if you'd like to strive towards "Strunk and White" it would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The +2 is when you make a suggested edit, which is when you don't have enough rep to perform edits on your own. When one of your suggested edits is accepted, you gain +2 rep - your retag efforts fall under here. Once you reach the rep levels for retags and edits on your own, you don't gain that suggested edit bonus.