# Force answers as accepted

Tags: discussion

Some users do not mark an answer as "solved my question", even though they leave a comment stating it solved the issue. For example [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/477846/308164).

What can be made about it? Can a flag be issued in order for moderators to mark as accepted? These type of cases seem to me unambiguous.

Ps: in my view this is not a duplicate of "force leavers" [question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5440/forcing-leavers-to-accept-an-answer/5443#5443), as my point is not directly about leavers (OP was active 6 days ago), and refers to questions where it is unambiguous that an answer solved the problem (via an explicit comment).

Comment: I disagree that the linked question is not related to this one, they ask the same thing, from a different perspective "What to do with unaccented answers" this is also related http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2869/encouraging-new-users-to-accept-answers and this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1519/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-an-answer-for-his-her-question and many more.

Comment: Yes, but here it is about a question **where the author has explicitly stated an answer solved his of her problem**. That is just different from marking as solved in the case of "leavers". Actually, the one who asked the question in my case is not a "leaver" at all. Last activity was 6 days ago.

Comment: You are missing my point, I am not saying they are one and the same, just related, notice I did not VTC. They are both about Un-accepted answers, you are both just coming at it from a diffident angle. There are many questions about this and they are all "related".

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I interpreted relatedness with duplicateness. Yes, they are related. I wanted to prevent any duplicate flag.

Comment: This is meta, no one is really that bothered, things come around again and again. Most questions on here could probably be duped by the main sites standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can a flag be issued in order for moderators to mark as accepted?

Please don't! **We can't mark the question as accepted. Only the OP can.** As a third party, all you can really do is spot good answers and vote for them.

The system (at least these days) will suggest you mark the question as accepted if you try to thank the answerer so that should be pushing a few new users toward that end.

Some users comment too (~"If this helped, consider marking this as the accepted answer") but that really only works on active users who are still around and should not be done in bulk (you'll hammer the homepage with answered stuff) and certainly not for posts from 2014. It can also seem a little desperate.

People *occasionally* not following through is just a cost of doing business here. It's not fatal and it doesn't stop other people voting for your answers (which a new user couldn't anyway).

Comment: I would like to add here. Even if it is not yours and if you see a question with a "thanks that worked" comment but no accept, you should comment something like"Glad that fixed your issue, if you want to thank the the user, please consider clicking the checkmark on the right, it really helps out". You would be surprised how many of these users simply do not know to accept but still stop by sometimes, happy users, mostly, comeback.

Comment: Btw, the OP is not a "leaver". Last activity was 6 days ago.

Comment: @luchonacho A comment should do the trick then :)

Comment: Naturally. I will try to see if it works.

Comment: @luchonacho Already did it :)

Comment: ‘that […] should not be done in bulk (you'll hammer the homepage with answered stuff) and certainly not for posts from 2014.’ — Why not? Accepting an answer does not bump a question in the recent tab. Neither do comments.