# How should I deal with old unanswered questions that are unlikely to be answered satisfactorily?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, old-questions

I'd like to have my accepted answer rate increase from 57%. What's dragging it down, though, is that I've posted a number of specific and/or difficult questions that haven't been answered, are unlikely to be answered satisfactorily, and for which I'm no longer interested in an answer (possibly because the question is obsolete).

See, for example:

- [Toggling between Unity 2D and 3D](https://askubuntu.com/q/56210/13398)
- [Constraint-based software to help with scheduling](https://askubuntu.com/q/35691/13398)

What is the proper way to deal with such questions? Is it to close the questions? Write a non-answer and accept it? Something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're no longer interested in an answer to the question just leave a comment stating just that. Then flag the question to be closed as "Too Localized" and a moderator will come by and review it.

Answer (score 1):

It's been my experience that leaving a comment is likely enough. The review team is pretty good about closing questions that fit the non-reproducable category. I don't see a need to involve the moderators in something this simple. Mentioning your concerns in [the General chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) should be enough to get the team to assist with closing the question.