# Why should I close 54422?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, deleted-questions, specific-question, old-questions

Someone has suggested I delete/close [Is there a way to disable or limit system xrandr probes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54422/is-there-a-way-to-disable-or-limit-system-xrandr-probes) because I am no longer experiencing the bug that prompted me to ask it.

Personally, I think it's still an interesting question that an experienced X.Orger could answer (even if to say, "sorry, it's not possible"), and might be useful to others with the same or similar problems. (I guess this is the opposite of http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1898/how-should-i-deal-with-old-unanswered-questions-that-are-unlikely-to-be-answered where the OP wants to get rid of a question that doesn't directly affect them any more.)

Are these reasons inappropriate? Why should I close this question?

(Bonus: Should I reword it to minimise/remove references my original issue? In this particular case should I ask to migrate it to Unix/Linux SE?)

Comment: Try something like 'Can I safely disable xrandr probing as a workaround to a known bug?' You'll keep getting flagged as a bug report probably (it happens), but it's a good question and you are staying on top of it. Edit+Bounty FTW, as Oli said below. I put 100 pts on it out of curiosity.

Comment: Are you still experiencing it with the old kernel? If we can't get feedback from you, it's difficult to provide an answer. :)

Comment: @htorque I think the question now is 'Can I disable xrandr probes without causing system problems' (Disregarding the bug issue).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you still want to know the answer to something to a valid question and can maintain the question (keep up with comments/edits), there's no reason to close the question.

In my opinion this isn't a bug report, it's asking for a way to disable xrandr from doing something, and you're perfectly active with it so it's fine.

In terms of going forward:

- A rewrite would be advisable. Make it less about the bug and more about what you're trying to achieve.
- Involve the people that suggested it in the first place. Ask them to post an answer if they know how (even if it's "can't be done")
- Bounties are a good motivator for tough questions.

Answer (score 2):

If your answer is "its a bug", then its technically off-topic and should be closed as such.

[What to do with questions that describe bugs?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs)

Comment: Agreed. I would say my question is "How can I do X? (btw, I'm doing it to work around a bug)" and therefore the answer is not "its a bug". The answer would be "you can't do X" or "to do X, follow steps 1 2 3"

Answer (score 0):

well... if i have the same bug in the future.. i'll be happy to have the page with the answer already there.. instead of having to research/formulate/check responses/choose answer ..  but that's me..  :)

unless the bug is completely eradicated from all present and future versions..in my opinion it should stay..