# what to do with questions without an owner?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with abandoned questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1843/what-to-do-with-abandoned-questions)

what is the guidlines for questions without an owner?

- Should they be closed?
- should they be maintained by anyone?

what's the deal?

like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22402/will-ubuntu-11-04-work-on-my-old-pc) question, should it be closed or kept open?

Comment: it's a dupe, thanks! :)