# Is it worth the effort of splitting up multiple questions that get posted as one post?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes people post multiple questions at once like so:

- [Customizing Gnome Shell in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79812/customizing-gnome-shell-in-11-10)

This is unfortunate because each one of those would be great standalone questions that would show up in searches better, etc.

I was mulling if splitting it up and reposting the rest as CW would be a good idea but that's quite invasive to the original question, so I just asked here.

Comment: Keep in mind that any answers that were already posted would need to be dealt with accordingly, especially ones that become partially or completely off-topic with regards to the original question after the split. (See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2005/how-should-answers-to-questions-that-have-since-been-split-be-dealt-with)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit invasive, but that's not *too* bad if you wait for the original question to be answered first.

If you leave a comment explaining why it would be better, you can give the OP a chance to do it himself as well.

Comment: I somehow think it'd be better to try and get these questions split before answers start coming in. See the Meta question I linked above for a reason why.