# Pro-forma comments now support remote sources, should we set this up?

Tags: discussion, comments

Pro-forma comments (the tool that let's us quickly paste precanned comments for common user questions now supports hosting the comments on a remote server:

- https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

We have quite a collection of [community maintained comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share), should we the AU community provide this as a service to our users so we can make it easier to maintain and for newer contributors to use?

We need a place to host the json file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've set this up.

They are [available on GitHub here](https://github.com/askubuntu/ProFormaComments), so if:

- you have an additional comment that you would like added after it has been added to that meta post
- you notice a typo or something

Fork and submit a pull request. Or ping me on chat, and I'll give you a hand.

To use this repo, add the following as a remote source in the script:

> https://raw.github.com/AskUbuntu/ProFormaComments/master/comments.jsonp

Opera users will need to use a mirror set up by [Nathan Osman](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) (updates hourly):

> http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/au/pro-forma/comments.jsonp