# Repeated "warnings" across questions and answers across StackExchange?

Tags: support

Sometimes I will come across a "warning" on an answer or question.  Sort of.

On my [super-old first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/97236/39869) that I answered, I got this "warning":

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be
>   preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and
>   provide the link for reference.

I thought that was just a normal comment on my question, so I ignored it.

Later then I was getting more involved into Askubuntu.  That's when I saw the same message across [low-quality posts](https://askubuntu.com/review).  Again and again.

Next I received another comment warning me to accept more questions that I asked.  This time I took it more seriously (although the poster wasn't a moderator) because I saw the same message before on somebody else's question.

Recently I also saw a warning about using bounties correctly somewhere on both StackOverFlow **and** AskUbuntu.

The same thing in common on those warnings is that they seem to be created by a robot (no offense if you the reader created them).

I know this may sound like a stupid question, but where do these repeated "warning" comments come from, and why do people want to use them when they can make up their own?

Comment: **ALL** those comments are written by us, very much humans (Sorry Jorge and George. :P). We are lazy, so we use pro forma comments. See the answer below.

Comment: Sorry for that...  But seeing them appearing everywhere really freaks me out.

Comment: may be we should add 'this is not a bot comment' at the end of all proforma comments. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is from our Pre-written Pro forma userscript comments:

- [What prewritten Pro-forma userscript comments can we use and share?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share)

An advice:

Don't ignore such comments from other community members , Review your post if you got such comments. If you have doubts about it ,contact the commentor in chat

Comment: @Eliah Kagan: thanks for the edit .link option is not available in mobile version :(

Comment: use plain markdown, silly. `[link text](http://my-link.watever)`

Comment: @tachyons Thanks for the answer!  Before I will freak out when I see those kind of comments.  I won't anymore.

Comment: BTW I can't find the bounty warning on that page

Comment: Which page? Which post?

Comment: I mean the Pro-Forma userscript page.  And I updated my super-old-first-answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid those specific comments by editing and fixing your answers to not be just links to blogs or forums. For example your first old answer links to a post with a broken image, no wonder it's getting downvotes!

I use these on Low Quality Posts as well, an answer that is just a link is basically a person going into google and then pasting a link, which is what we don't really do here, we strive to be the place where people end up after searching in Google, and having the information in a post that can be edited and improved on over time (and kept up to date!) is always preferable to blogs and forums.