# How to back up and restore customized pro-forma userscript comments?

Tags: support, comments

I have extensively customized my [pro-forma userscript comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share) (with new comments and new wordings/linkifications for default ones). I use Chromium as my browser most of the time, and Firefox occasionally. (My pro-forma userscript comments are stored in Chromium.)

How can I back up, and restore, these comments? I can back up my entire profile, which contains them. But I'd like to be able to restore them to a different profile, so that I can retain them in these sorts of situations:

- I switch profiles.
- I use another machine, or another browser.
- I experience data loss.
- I want to clear out my browser profile, to fix/troubleshoot some unrelated problem.

In case it's relevant, I mostly use Ubuntu as my operating system (which may not come as a surprise).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now create remote Pro-forma comment repositories. [We've set one up already for shared common pro-forma comments](https://github.com/askubuntu/ProFormaComments). You can do the same by uploading a jsonp file somewhere and just referencing it on all your installs.

If you'd like to add some of the ones you use more frequently to the shared repository, please feel free to do so!