# Just a reminder for reviewers: a comment is not always needed

Tags: discussion, review

When reviewing "Low Quality Posts" you are asked what comment you want to add.

If there a̳l̳r̳e̳a̳d̳y̳ is an appropriate comment on the post don't add your own - just select

- no comment needed

Comment: this again? http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4219/169736 can a mod feature the other? pliz???

Comment: @Braiam Yep. Needs to be underlined *yet again*.

Comment: @Seth yep, double underlined has been applied.