# Deleted comment left a notification

Tags: support

I was reviewing some questions from new users, and my inbox button blinked. I clicked on it, to see this :

[image: inbox]

Leading [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402500/wine-cant-load-module-p11-kit-trust-so/471571?noredirect=1#comment624394_471571).

The problem, is that this comment doesn't exist, I apparently did not commented that post, or my comment was deleted, I don't know : I don't recall having commented that post, and I see no issues with the main post that would have required me to comment on an "issue".

The inbox message appeared the exact same time than the the post was "protected by community".

Although I usually wouldn't care for a notification leading nowhere, here, there's apparently something that I did wrong, but I'm unable to understand what, why or when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup that was me. Hopefully a screenshot will help clarify the situation:

[image]

I converted the post to a comment right after adding my comment.  As you can see in the URL you gave:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/402500/wine-cant-load-module-p11-kit-trust-so/471571?noredirect=1#comment624394_471571
```

This bit: `471571` points to the answer, and this bit:

```
?noredirect=1#comment624394_471571
```

Points to my comment.  However, since you don't have [access to moderator tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege the link just drops you at the question. I know this can be really confusing sometimes!

Anyway, I was just asking you not to add another comment to posts that already have one that addresses the issue. If you are reviewing through the low quality post queue there is an option of "No comment needed" in case someone has already added one:

[image]

For more information, see [this meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4219/psa-when-reviewing-dont-post-duplicate-and-near-duplicate-comments).

Don't worry, you aren't in trouble, it was just a friendly tip :)

Comment: Oh I didn't saw the "No comment needed" ! Okay, I understand now, I did not link "me pressing the button" with "the program automatically leaving a comment like if I wrote it myself". Thanks ! I think I might have done that somewhere else, though... In the past hour.

Comment: @MrVaykadji You aren't the first to not notice that option, so don't feel too bad about it :)