# How does this happen? Or When to comment on an Answer?

Tags: bug, review

[image: Screenshot]

---

Whenever reviewing Low-Quality Posts (Answers) I generally choose to comment if appropriate situation is detected, But if a comment is present on the answer already, should I select **No comment Needed** option?

Comment: I think that's a bug. Normally, when you choose the same comment, the existing coment is upvoted.

Comment: @terdon yes, I've seen it multiple times

Comment: This is an older post by Eliah https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4219 which is very related to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, hello there! I see my name. Cool.

What *should* happen is that you select an existing comment and the existing one gets upvoted.

What *does* happen is that a second comment gets posted. Meh.

So, while we're grounded in reality instead of our ideal fantasies, the best course of action is to upvote the existing comment and select the *No Comment Needed* option. See [Eliah's excellent writeup](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4219/psa-when-reviewing-dont-post-duplicate-and-near-duplicate-comments) (let's ignore the fact that the words "Eliah" and "excellent" are redundant) on this topic.

If you see this happen, feel free to also flag the later comment as obsolete/not constructive/a duplicate. They're basically free flags at that point.

Comment: ++ for the redundancy :-)