# PSA: 12.10 Release Day Today (aka: time to rock and roll!)

Tags: discussion

Some tips for helping when the site gets busy:

- Lots of new attention and traffic means it's usually an influx of duplicate questions, especially the easy ones, so keep an eye out for dupes.
- Some users don't write descriptive questions, editing as they come in is very useful and helps point people in the right direction. No one wants to read an entire page of "ubuntu 12.10 firefox problem" style questions.
- When we're really busy sometimes people stumble over each other on the brand new incoming questions -- I hit pages 2-3 during the release to find questions that might have been bumped off too soon.
- Check out these [pro forma comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-pro-forma-comments-do-you-use), they help when trying to guide new users.

Who knows, this might lead to a nice influx of new users, so good luck everyone, I get the feeling we're going to be busy!

Comment: Shamelessly borrowed from Jorge Castros previous post.

Comment: I feel as if [tag:crash](291 times) and [tag:error](64 times) are being used quite often. Can we get temporary legislation to do something about it?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: <s>Temporary</s> Permanent decree: GO EDIT THEM OUT. :)

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ I think of them like honeypots, places to spend your close votes on!