# In answers attributed to "community wiki", what does the percentage value denote?

Tags: support, community-wiki

See [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1327/25656) for example:

> community wiki
>   28 revs, 9 users **37%**
>   Jorge Castro

What does **37%** denote?

I looked at [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) but didn't see an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the percentage of the answer that is written by that person, so I wrote 37% of that answer.

Comment: In terms of characters added? Characters removed? Both? Weghted?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Presumably it is percentage of characters *present* in the current revision.