# How do I flag my question for re-opening?

Tags: support, flagging

Sometimes questions get closed as a duplicate, when they might not be one.

A comment should be left by the close-voter for the user explaining how to get their question re-opened if the duplicate doesn't solve their problem (also asking for the reason *why* it doesn't solve the problem).

So now, how does one flag their question for re-opening?

Comment: I often find that editing the question for reopening, and mentioning how it's been improved, and posting it on meta with a great explanation on why it deserves be opened helps massively in most places. Assuming enough users with reopen votes are around, it works quite well. I have not seen this in AU yet, so YMMV ;)

Comment: I agree.  Questions can be re-opened quite fast when there is a meta post.  And yes, it *does* happen on AU ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To flag your question for re-opening, click on "flag"  at the bottom of the question, near the tag area.

[image]

Then in the "Other" section add a message for the moderators.  (It's usually better to be descriptive)

[image]

And click "Flag Question".

If you have at [least 5 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) you can  also [ask a question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask) here on meta, asking for your question to be re-opened.