# How can I ask to reopen a question after I edited it?

Tags: support, closed-questions, review

I edited this closed as off-topic question to be more general: [Should I use ZimageZ in Xubuntu xfce to store my screenshots?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254232/should-xubuntu-use-zimagez-in-xfce-to-store-your-screenshots#comment318627_254232)

Do I have to ask here in Meta to review a closed question after I edited it ([like someone asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254232/should-xubuntu-use-zimagez-in-xfce-to-store-your-screenshots#comment318627_254232) ) ?
How will the users that voted for closing in the first place notice that I edited it and it could be reopened?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is the answer:

To flag your question for re-opening, click on "flag" at the bottom of the question, near the tag area.

see [How do I flag my question for re-opening?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/34298)

Comment: I'm going to edit that question to make it more general.  More of "How do I get my post re-opened".