# How can a low-reputation user dispute a "closed as too localized"?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I posted [question 62034](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62034/is-it-possible-to-set-the-default-behaviour-of-double-clicking-a-folder-to-be-o) asking if/how I can change the default behaviour in PCManFM (Lubuntu's default file manager) from "open in new tab" to "open in new window".

I gave a lot of context and even a crude screencast because people asked for clarification. (eg. "Right-clicking and choosing 'open in new window'" isn't acceptable because I'm trying to save my mother the hassle of doing it,  without fail, every single time she opens a folder... which is what she currently does.)

It's now been closed for being "too localized" despite being far more generally-applicable than a lot of the questions I've seen left open.

As I'm quite skilled in Linux use in general and I've never cared for GNOME or Unity-based desktops, my reputation is almost exclusively over on StackOverflow where people ask more questions I can answer.

How can someone with only 240 reputation on AskUbuntu dispute an erroneous "closed as too localized"?

Comment: A moderator as re-opened your question.  Also, all you need to do to get a question re-opened is to come and ask nicely, explaining why your question should re-reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, here are the two most effective ways to ask for a question to be reopened:

1. [Flag the question.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/22949) If your account is registered with a verified email address, I've been informed that you do *not* need 15 reputation to flag *your own posts.*
2. If you have at least 5 reputation, post on meta.

If you think it's quite clear that your question ought to be reopened, based on additional information you've provided (usually by editing the question itself, but occasionally you might provide it just in comments), it's probably easier and faster to flag it. Use a custom moderator attention flag for this, so you're typing a message into a text box. Make sure the message clearly explains why the question should be reopened.

If you think there might be disagreement about whether or not the question should be reopened, you may want to post here on meta instead, so the matter can be discussed.

Answer (score 8):

Since, it was a question posted about 1.5 years ago with no valuable answers and last edit to the question too was about 10 months back - it seemed to be abandoned. Closing such old questions are part of the clean-up efforts which community members take up on a regular basis.

"Too Localized" close reason is used for closing most of the abandoned questions because they generally do not help future visitors or the question becomes obsolete/irrelevant after newer distribution releases.

Since, you are still looking for answers to that question and have already posted this on Meta - I believe it would get reopened shortly. Members with more than 3000 Reputation have the [privilege to cast Reopen Votes](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions). Moreover, a moderator may also chip in to expedite in Reopening the question.