# How can I revive the pro-forma script after a failed loading of "remote"?

Tags: support, comments

Following the [question about pro-forma comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share) I installed them and then tried to enable the remote source, which seemingly failed (at least it took a very long time ™ without any noticeable network activity).

So I finally cancelled the process. Result: whenever I click on *auto* nothing seems to happen at all. I disabled, then uninstalled and reinstalled the script - nothing.

This happened in chromium as well as in firefox - I'd like to get back to the local version for now.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and cookies? First step when troubleshooting browser problems :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by a typo in the remote source. Thanks to @AmithKK, this was fixed yesterday and the remote scripts are working now.

I had experienced the same problem. When running with the remote URL set in the script, the only pop-up that worked for me was in the review queue. On Meta and AU the script would do nothing.

To resolve:

- Remove the extension
- Clear the browser cache (with *empty the cache* and *Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data options* selected)
- Re-install the extension

This brought me back to the local version.

Comment: I just got this problem myself.  Something is wrong with the remote source... or maybe the script.

Comment: (Ping @Guntbert)

There was a typo in the remote source [here](https://github.com/AskUbuntu/ProFormaComments)

This has been fixed in the next commit [23905afd80785de32450b538b8507f46555884e1](https://github.com/AskUbuntu/ProFormaComments/commit/23905afd80785de32450b538b8507f46555884e1)

Comment: @AmithKK thx for the quick fix, got it working now :-))