# What is the process to get those pro-forma-comments into the "central script"?

Tags: discussion, comments

I am referring to the comments suggested in answers to [share prewritten pro-forma-userscript comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share).

Need they upvoting or do they just need someone to do the work? (that someone could be me, of course...)

Comment: I've removed the [tag:feature-request] tag because you don't seem to ask for a feature.  You can add it back later, but please clarify on this "feature" :)

Comment: I think those who have access to the github account will be reviewing how we do pull requests going forward to avoid breakage.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: @Seth thats fine with me, I was thinking along the line "I want something improved" and added it, but it is clearly solved :-))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you talking about the remote sources?  Those are hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/) for all to contribute to.

The project's page is here:  [AskUbuntu / ProFormaComments](https://github.com/AskUbuntu/ProFormaComments).

I must admit, it was my addition that caused that last parse error and made everything stop working ;)  Thanks to AmithKK for finding and fixing it.

So, in order to get comments into the script, someone needs to fork the GitHub repo and submit a pull request.  If you don't have a GitHub account, or find the process confusing (it is!), just ask someone else to do it for you :)

**I have detailed the process for the curious:**

First you need to fork the comments repo:

[image]

Then click on the file you want to edit (in this case `comments.jsonp`):

[image]

Next click "Edit":

[image]

Make your changes then add a summary and description describing your changes.  Click "Submit Changes".

[image]

At this point your changes are only in your copy of the repository.  To get them into the central script you'll have to submit a pull request. I recommend clicking "Raw"  and using the URL to test your script before doing that.

When you're ready to submit your request, click "Pull Request" near the top.

[image]

Type out a title and description for your request and click "Submit pull request".

[image]

You're done!  Your pull request has been submitted for the mods to review.

The comments are in `jsonp`, you'll have to use this format when submitting a request:

```
{ "name": "[Q][A]Name in quotes", "description": "full comment in quotes"},
```

`[Q]` is used to mark comments that are for questions and `[A]` for comments that are used for answers.  This is the basic pattern for [Javascript Object Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 4):

The script we use here uses a [json file](https://raw.github.com/askubuntu/ProFormaComments/master/comments.jsonp) containing a set of useful comments. It is [hosted](https://github.com/askubuntu/ProFormaComments) on github and instructions for using it are included in the [top answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1327/1992).

To get yours submitted to this central script, you will need to make a pull request via github. It is really easy and simple to do, and I've added some comments this way myself.

Comment: Easy and simple?  That's an overstatement.. IMO anyway.

Comment: @Seth Might not be a bad Q&A topic perhaps? I found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaNGbk6HN9Y) tutorial series very useful when I was starting out with git and github

Comment: @maggotbrain I'll have to look at that video.  I find the way GitHub operates rather confusing.. Would make a good Q/A :)