# Can we have a post with all "standard" replies to incorrect posts?

Tags: discussion, moderation

We are expected to leave a comment whenever we find(and take action on) a wrong post, let it be

- Duplicates
- wrong use of comments and answers
- serial editing cases
- Off-topic posts
- all other cases

So can we have a meta post(probably this one) that contains all "standard"(acceptable by the majority) replies to all such posts. This would be a big post, but we could add them in a user script like https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments so as to access them quickly.

Comment: We already have. It's http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-aka-autoreviewcomments-userscript-comments-can-we-us.