# How do I add URLs to comments and what are available aliases like [edit]?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I can't quite get how to add inline links to comments. There are some aliases like`[edit]` but I see that people add other useful links this way. Where can I find list of these aliases, or add inline links manually?

I found this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000) in StackExcange meta.

But I am sure there are some others too.

Comment: Standard way is `[link name](http://link.url)`.

Comment: But where do I find list of predefined links?

Comment: If I could tell you, I would have written it as answer. I am interested in that too! :-)

Comment: The only alias I know is `[edit]` which turns to [edit].

Comment: Test howto [answer]

Comment: That meta post was written by an SE employee. It's unclear what more are you looking for. Do you think there are more than he said?

Comment: I am sure I saw some more. Like a link on help how to accept an answer. But I can't recall where was that. I thought there was some full list.

Comment: @Pilot6 That *is* the full list. That's it. If you find one that isn't there I will be very surprised.

Comment: That is what I looked for.

[Proforma comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1327/167850) that contain the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this Meta.Se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000):

> - `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't
>     have (or already is) a Meta site.
> - `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around.
> - `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is
>     respected).
> - `[help]` should be obvious. `[meta-help]` links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta), `[help/on-topic]` links to "What topics can I ask
>     about here?" (/help/on-topic), `[help/dont-ask]` links to "What types
>     of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask),
>     `[help/behavior]` links to "What kind of behavior is expected of
>     users?" (/help/behavior). Link text for all of these is "help center"
>     .
> - `[tour]` and `[meta-tour]` – equivalent to the FAQ version, but links to the site's Tour page (resp. the meta site's Tour page).
>     Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy names
>     `[about]` and `[meta-about]` are still supported.
> - `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the "How to Ask" / "How to Answer" page.
> - `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super
>     User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/),
>     [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [Area
>     51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), the [Stack Exchange
>     portal](http://stackexchange.com/)). Link text is the site name.
> - `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for
>     Ask Ubuntu. `[meta.something.se]` links to the meta site.
> - `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for SO,
>     http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ for Meta SE,
>     http://chat.stackexchange.com/ everywhere else, that last one
>     showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text
>     being "{site name} Chat".

Comment: @Tim what's the point of that edit? `[unix.se]` is already covered by `[something.se]`. `[ubuntu.se]` is mentioned because it is an exception to the other specially-named sites.

Comment: because it's caled Unix and Linux.

Comment: @Tim So? The site is still `unix.stackexchange.com`, not `unix-and-linux.stackexchange.com`. Same for Vi & Vim, which is `vi.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: okay, that's fine :)