# Suggestion - Add a request for additional hardware information to close votes

Tags: discussion

Currently when using close votes there are a number of suggestions (as you know).

I would like to suggest a close vote to request hardware information.

For example, [Microphone Volume changing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628053/microphone-volume-changing-randomly)

It is not really possible to answer the question without a lot of more detailed information (and audio configuration / jack are not standard to the desktop spins)

The closest close vote we have is

> unclear what you're asking
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Similar questions include other hardware problems, video cards, wirelesss, and audio are probably the top 3.

I know one can always leave a comment asking for additional information, but it seems such questions are prone to becoming abandoned.

Please consider adding a close vote along the lines of

```
Insufficient hardware information

Please clarify your question by adding specific hardware information
including the output of `lspci -v` 
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details 
for additional information.
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't disagree with the sentiment but I think a close-vote is altogether too slow. If the post dawdled through the queue, it could take all day before the OP saw the close message and knew they needed to add the information.

We already have a solid mechanism: **Post your request for more information as a comment, and vote to close as unclear**.

That way they get instant feedback and if they fix their post up, we can kick it out of the close queue early on without needing to fully close and then fully reopen. Much quicker, much nicer (new users see closures as a slap in the face) and less review intensive.

---

As an aside/extension, I'd like to see automated requests for hardware information when they're submitting the post. If it's about wireless for one example, why not ask them for the output of `lspci | grep -i net`? Pet peeve for a while but there doesn't appear to be the momentum upstairs to get this done.

Comment: Is there an automated canned response to ask for hardware info ? Gets old typing "please identify your wireless card" or "update your question with the output of ..." or pastebin ....

Comment: @bodhi.zazen [Yes indeed!](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) then take a look at http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-aka-autoreviewcomments-userscript-comments-can-we-us.