# Feature request: canned answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

It would be nice to have boiler-plate answers we can post without having to type them out all the time.

Something akin to this: [I don't know where to post this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164196/i-dont-know-where-to-post-this/1164205#1164205)

Forgive me for poorly worded question I'm kind of community brain-storming here.

Comment: +1: I don’t agree, but it’s a useful question!

Answer (score 7):

This is not answering the question for canned answers because I don’t see a valid usecase for them. Unlike a comment, an answer is as unique as a question, and if it’s not unique then it’s a duplicate.

---

> this answer which is nothing more than an extended-length, nicely-formatted comment

As you agree this is actually not an answer, we don’t need that for *answers* but rather for (nicely formatted) *comments* – meet the AutoReviewComments userscript:

[AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116)

Combined with some canned comments from this Meta this is a powerful weapon in the daily wars out there, e.g. from:

[What prewritten Pro-forma (aka AutoReviewComments) userscript comments can we use and share?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1323/507051)