# Post Reviewing Useful Comments

Tags: support, comments, review, review-queue

I have seen the same set of comments being used by many reviewers. Can an experienced reviewer please provide a list of those comments? Here's one:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Comment: @Zanna Do you realize that that is one of my own questions? anyway if you read the chat, you will realise that it didin't work as it is supposed to

Comment: Related; [What prewritten Pro-forma (aka AutoReviewComments) userscript comments can we use and share?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1323/480481)

Answer (score 2):

That particular comment is automatically generated by the system through the Low Quality Posts review queue. I'm not sure if there is a list of these (so you can copy them) but you can see all options [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143667/29523):

[image]

Nowadays, the comments have some links in them, but the text hasn't changed significantly over the years.

Other interesting links:

- [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136609/295232)
- [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061)