# Hi, how can i remove this account?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This particular site of stack exchange is not amusing me, has no function and has over zealous moderators who deleted every single one of my posts, two of which because i mentioned that unity is a bug filled useless piece of code (which was very relevant to the question, but which they put 'was not relevant' with no recourse whatsoever) and one because, well because they just wanted to. i rate it lower than zero, and want it removed from my list of stack exchange sites but i dont want to remove my whole stack exchange login. thanks. to the moderators who deleted my relevant posts, what kind of overzealous idiots are you ?

Comment: seems they can delete any relevant answer i give in five minutes, but this one takes a little longer.

Answer (score 17):

I'm sorry to hear you've had such a negative experience with Ask Ubuntu. First of all allow me to address each one of your points, then if you still wish to remove your account instructions will be outlined at the bottom.

I've reviewed each of the answers in question and would like to shed some light on each.

1. This was the first answer I reviewed. Since it's been deleted I've included the body of the text with a link. As you may well know, nothing is ever really "deleted", you can always view questions and answers that have been deleted as well as the comments attached to them.

   > [I would suggest that unity is a 'bug' in the thinking of ubuntu developers. Why o why did they start doing that when there is so many other things to do ! :) set session to classic mode to turn it off. (you then have to fiddle around with compiz setup, but youll get it)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69102/compiz-grid-feature-abruptly-stopped-working-correctly-now-ctrl-alt-num-4-an/90035#90035)

   I agree with the course of action taken here. The user was specifically asking for a solution to an issue which, according to the comments, turned out to be a bug. The bug was reported, a patch was created, and is now fixed. [Bug reports are off-topic for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) to begin with. That being said, your question neither addresses the issue or provides any fruitful actions for the user. Simply saying "unity is a 'bug'" and informing the user to disable unity isn't really a solution. It parallels a similar scenario of "My Microsoft Windows computer used to open Word Documents but now doesn't" then replying "Windows is a virus, you should buy a Mac". As you can see, this isn't really a solution to the problem at all. At best your answer was a comment, one posed in jest at your apparent dislike of a Desktop Shell.
2. Similar to the previous example, you answered a question about LibreOffice Unity Launcher not working, your reply:

   > [Unity is a new device tagged on to an operating system with already too many graphical choices, it looks awful, is buggy, hooks into compiz in horrible awful ways, does nothing useful and totally confuses me why someone would bother doing such a thing, the only solution is using 'classic' mode and uninstalling anything with unity in the name.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47914/libreoffice-unity-launcher-doesnt-work/90995#90995)

   Again, this question ended up being a bug, and was closed; however, your proposed "solution" offers nothing that addresses the issue at hand, a user is having a problem performing X on Y. Your proposed solution is to forget about Y and just switch to Z.
3. This is the final answer you've provided on the site. Unlike the previous two you've attempted to reach out to the user who asked the question and collect additional information:

   > [is it the case that when you have set your router to accept any non-WPA connections you forgot to erase the settings from 'edit connections' in Network Manager ? Reason I ask is because your non-WPA connection shows wpa-supplicant having an error which i thought was the program that deals with WPA connections. For non WPA connections i think it shouldnt be using that, so perhaps you have switched it to an OPEN network but forgot to change your settings on your client to reflect that ? Assuming your ubuntu install is a fresh one and you havent fiddled too much, this looks to me like a router issue, try another router to double check if possible.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22247/wireless-will-not-connect/90999#90999)

   This is a great attempt to further hone in on the issue and reach a solution, so I will have to apologize for the confusion. Your answer wasn't actually deleted, it was instead converted to a comment on the original question. Since you're posing several questions to the author these are better served as comments. I likely don't have to remind you, since you are a Stack Exchange veteran, that all users need [50 reputation points in order to post comments on any posts other than their own](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment). So, one of our moderators converted the answer for you. You can visit the question, click "See all comments" and confirm it's been moved.

---

I hope the above sheds some light on what you've referred to as "overzealous moderation" from the "overzealous idiot" moderator team. In all honesty, with the exception of the last post, your posts were flagged by members of our community. As I'm sure you're aware, given your Stack Exchange history, moderators work the majority of their actions as an extension of what the community dictates. Each post in question, with the exception of the last one, were flagged by community members bringing to our attention the sub-par nature of the content.

If you still want just your Ask Ubuntu account removed, we'd be happy to help and finish that process for you. Just drop a comment on this post with something to the tune of "Please continue with the deletion of my account" and it'll be done shortly after your reply.

Comment: wow a novel. delete me please, this only further goes to show a remarkable anality and twisting of my words. the fact that unity is SO BUGGY, looks crap, and serves no purpose whatsoever other than making people who dont know anything about computers feel that ubuntu is a bit more like a mac and ergo friendlier than pc is the point i was making, not 'youve got a spectrum and ive got a commodore' - but i can see if someone was bored and wanted to poke holes in what i said then you could make up rubbish like you just did in great detail. it only proves my point that the two posts were BUGS.

Comment: a user is having a problem performing X on Y. Your proposed solution is to forget about Y and just switch to Z. = this is EXACTLY what im saying YES. DUH. what so you would suggest continuing banging your head against something that just doesnt work then ? again. more reason for leaving, tech peeps here dont know anything.

Comment: @lolfrog Now cracks a noble heart. Good-night, sweet prince; And flights of angels sing thee to thy rest.

Comment: This question, Marco's answer and subsequent comments report the (negative) experience of a single individual. Btw, the question is "how to remove AskUbuntu account", but there no instruction to do it (I can just deduct your account can be deleted asking to moderators). At the moment this q&a can't be useful for future users. So I'd suggest to either add the answer on how to remove the account or to delete the question.

Comment: Woah! ^^^ Most epic user generated Meta post ever :D

Comment: @igi There is another thread about that. Not every Meta question has to have lasting value as a reference - some are completely functional and those posts are just as important for the running of the site.

Comment: I have just posted a relevant [Meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2378/18612) regarding how exactly we should handle "forget *Y*, switch to *Z*" answers.

Comment: A novel indeed! Well done.

Answer (score 10):

I deleted two of your posts. One rant and the one that was converted to a comment because it was a series of questions, not an answer. Marco is completely correct in his reasoning.

- Answers-to-comments is standard fare. The users and moderators here are pretty attentive so we deal with more than what you might be used to.
- Rants are very, *very* rarely any use to anybody. As I pointed out in my comment, we are not a forum for people just to "me too", "Unity tuk auer jawbs!", etc along with the OP. Other people, people not me, were voting against your post *and* flagging it for moderator attention... So I took action and here we are.

Considering your account has been deleted now I'm not sure if you'll ever come back to check to see why we're "overzealous idiots", but I thought I should say something as 66% of your problem is me.

As you'll hopefully come to accept one day, I am but a channel for the rules of Ask Ubuntu. If you disagree with those rules, you're welcome to start a thread on Meta to discuss what posts are acceptable.