# Is suggesting the use of another Linux distribution valid?

Tags: discussion

Much of what I know has come from using Ubuntu but also several other distributions.  I recently suggesting a user use Puppy Linux because they needed something that could fit on a CD (<700mb).  I was informed it wasn't appropriate for askubuntu.

Is it okay to point people toward other distributions if those distributions have useful tools for the task they are asking about?

Comment: Older live Ubuntus did fit on a cd.

Comment: Related: [Should an answer like remove Ubuntu and install (insert distro here) be flagged / downvoted?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11725/should-an-answer-like-remove-ubuntu-and-install-insert-distro-here-be-flagged)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While we only directly support *questions* about the official spins, the following occurs to me:

- It's perfectly plausible that a person turns up with what *they* think is an Ubuntu problem but the best solution requires another distribution.
- It's arrogant to assume Ubuntu will *always* be best for every scenario.
- It's self-defeating to limit the site to *answers* that only mention Ubuntu-related things because that would —in these circumstances— mean we're excluding the best answer.

That said, if the question is "which version of Ubuntu will fit on a CD?",  "try Puppy" on its own is not a valid answer. **It doesn't answer the question.** But you could answer the Ubuntu question and then go on to add your recommendation. That only makes it a better answer in my eyes.

So [in this case](https://askubuntu.com/q/719944/449), if you were *sure* there are no Live **CD** versions of Ubuntu, you could say:

> There are no supported Live versions of Ubuntu that will fit on a CD.
>
> However there are other Live distributions of Linux that still target CDs and smaller. My favourite is... because... etc...

But that does also rely on you being technically correct. Which may not be the case. Lubuntu 14.04 is less than 700MB. Mentioning *all* of this in a structured and well-reasoned way would probably make for a pretty decent answer.

Comment: This is what I thought.  I love Ubuntu but it can't be the answer for everything.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Answer (score -4):

This site is called **Ask Ubuntu**.  Other distros are better mentioned on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

## ;-)

<sub>And even for Ubuntu-derived versions, have a look at the [officially supported versions here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors).</sub>