# Is it okay to suggest that my own question be closed since it's related to a confirmed bug?

Tags: support

The question is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71528/make-network-manager-restart-after-dropped-connection/99110#99110) and the bug seems to be [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ppp/+bug/869954). None of the "close" options seem appropriate. Perhaps, **exact duplicate** could be extended to **exact duplicate or existing bug**?

Comment: Having a new close reason, "Existing Bug", which links to a bug on Launchpad, would be nice. But it might also get confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with suggesting your question be closed (and it won't count against you in any way). As for bugs, [they should be closed as off-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs)

Comment: But I'm confused about which reason to select. If it does no harm, I don't have any problem with it remaining "open".

Comment: @vasa1 See also: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs). We've also added bug reports to [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) (under "This is not the right place for ..."). They can't be closed as duplicates because a dupe has to link to some other question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll go with "off-topic".