# What should we do with a question discovered to be related to a bug with a fix?

Tags: discussion

Let's suppose your system behaves strangely, but you can't tell if it is a bug. As a matter of fact, you think that it is a misconfiguration. You ask then a question in Ask Ubuntu and get some (tentative) answers. However, later you find out that it was not your fault, but an actual bug which has a *proposed* fix (but not yet implemented).

So, in this scenario, should we

1. post a comment with the launchpad report?
2. edit the question and state that «in the near future» you should only update/upgrade?
3. close the question?
4. answer the question with a link to the launchpad report (and its committed fix)?
5. answer *and* close the question?

There are similar questions [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2398/is-it-okay-to-suggest-that-my-own-question-be-closed-since-its-related-to-a-con) and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs), but they don't take into account the case of a committed fix.

Comment: Please reserve the [meta-tag:bug] tag for reporting actual bugs in the system.

Answer (score 1):

If the bug is fixed, you can answer with the fix and a link to the bug report, then vote to close, if it is just report, leave a comment and (when you have the rep) vote to close the question.

It is also good to tell the OP to go and report the bug at the given link.