# Is this a bug or a question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with questions that describe bugs?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs)

An user ask this [12.04 after latest update, no unity, no top bar, only wallpaper. Can you help?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121692/12-04-after-latest-update-no-unity-no-top-bar-only-wallpaper-can-you-help)
And I answer him.
In that case, I can answer helping him or I have to tell him that it is a bug and this site is not for bugs?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

Its both.

While it is a bug, it is also a duplicate of another question. So it doesn't really matter what it is. :)

Comment: But, my question is, what I have to do in the case that this is a bug?
I can help him? or I have to tell him that it is a bug and this forum is not for bugs?
I want to help but also, maintain the forum clean with his rules =)
Thank you

Comment: Oh, in that case this question is a duplicate. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs

Comment: Thank you for the answer =)