# Question closed as off topic, months later, with generic hint to read the FAQ

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My question [firefox addon "Deutsches Wörterbuch 2.0.2" full of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97449/firefox-addon-deutsches-worterbuch-2-0-2-full-of-errors) was closed and downvoted recently. Reason given: Off topic/RTFM.

In the faq I read:

> We welcome questions about:
>
> - Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

Firefox is a genuine Ubuntu program, and the plugin a third party software - isn't it?

Since I thought the location of the dictionary might be interesting I didn't asked at Superuser where I might had get Windows-answers.

Or what would you think would be the right place to ask?

In general - is it a good idea to close old questions everybody has forgotten and is losing time, reconstructing the thread and the situation it was asked? If people close fresh questions, it will have a positive effect on the time, people lose or save.

Another problem is the generic form of closing. Instead of "read the faq" the reason should be given explicitly. I'm now asking myself what is wrong, don't get it, start a meta thread. Much more work, than a short note in the comments, what closing users think the the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this was closed as a bug. I'm not sure why the comment didn't make it, but [bugs are off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs).

Comment: Why do you think it was closed as a bug?

Comment: @userunknown just a guess, because you talk about how there are a ton of errors there.